# How to make a custom array class return boolean value when it is empty

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a class as below:

```
class Fields implements ArrayAccess, Countable, SeekableIterator 
{
   $this->_fields = array();

   ...continue
}
```

I want to have my class have the following boolean capability

```
$myArray = new Fields();
if($myArray == false)
{
   echo 'It is empty';
}
```

How the above behaviour to be implemented in my class

Comment: Why don't you use `if ( empty($myArray) ) {`

Comment: I could use that, but I am asking whether it is possible or not

Comment: @Nelson Because that won't work?!

Comment: not even the Spl containers like `SplStack` have implemented such a thing, so I'd say it's not possible without writing a PHP Extension. But that's probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good solution for your "problem", but it works.

```
class Fields implements ArrayAccess, Countable, SeekableIterator 
{
  protected $_fields = array();

  // ...continue

  public function __invoke() {
    return $this->_fields == true;
  }
}
```

I simply implemented an `__invoke()` method, which gets called if the object gets used as a function.
If you now do the following, it works as expected.

```
$myArray = new Fields();
if($myArray() == false)
{
   echo 'It is empty';
}
```

This is probably not the best way or the way you should use `__invoke`, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but my question is can we implement such behaviour in a class